# problem solving by conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics

conditional probability

Professional athletes who play in the NLF are subject to random drug tests. Suppose the probability that the test shows a positive result given that the athlete is using drugs is 0.93 and the probability that the test shows a negative result given that the athlete is not using drugs is 0.98. Assume that three percent of the NFL players use drugs.

a) What is the probability that a NFL player chosen at random will test negative for drug use?

b) What is the probability that the player is actually using drugs given that he has a positive test?

Could you please help me with this question by given me any hint?

Comment: http://lesswrong.com/lw/2b0/bayes_theorem_illustrated_my_way/ best conditional probability intuitive guide I've seen but  bayes theorem is what your looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let event A=The player is using the drug

B=The player is not using the drug

P=The test result is positive.

N=The test result is negative.

We have $Pr(A)=0.03, Pr(B)=0.97$ and $Pr(P)+Pr(N)=1$

We also know $Pr(P|A)=0.93$ and $Pr(N|B)=0.98$.

(a)

By Law of Total Probability, we have

$Pr(N)=Pr(N|A)Pr(A)+Pr(N|B)Pr(B)=(1-Pr(P|A))Pr(A)+Pr(N|B)Pr(B)=(1-0.93)\times 0.03+0.98\times 0.97=0.9527$

(b)

By Bayes' Rule, we get

$Pr(A|P)=\frac{Pr(P|A)Pr(A)}{Pr(P)}=\frac{0.93\times 0.03}{1-0.9527}=0.5899$

Answer (score 0):

**1) What do you know?**

The first step is to summarise the information provided using the usual probability symbols.

Let $T$ be the event of a positive test; $D$ be the event of using; and $T^\complement,D^\complement$ their complements.   Then we have been told:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(T\mid D)=0.93 \\ \mathsf P(T^\complement\mid D^\complement)=0.98 \\ \mathsf P(D)=0.03\end{align}$$

**2) Where do you want to go?**

Once you have the "knowns", the second step is to do the same with the "unknowns".   What are we looking to find?

> a) What is the probability that a NFL player chosen at random will test negative for drug use?

$$\mathsf P(T^\complement)$$

> b) What is the probability that the player is actually using drugs given that he has a positive test?

$$\mathsf P(D\mid T)$$

**3) How do you get there?**

Once you've listed things in this manner, the path will often become clearer.   This problem is clearly dealing with *conditional probabilities*, so just ask what tools do you have in your kit to do so?

> The Law of Complements along the way, and (a) The Law of Total Probability, and (b) Bayes' Rule.

**4) Now, can you do this?**

Well?